# How can I isolate the log of a single method using apache LoggingInterceptor, Spring and log4j?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, log4j, jax-ws

I have a web service which publishes three methods and I use the LoggingInInterceptor, extending org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor, and LoggingOutInterceptor, extending org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor, for the logging.

The point is that I want to log the information about one of these methods in a separated file, but I don't know if that's possible. I need to do it wiht interceptors because the request and responses information is logged automatically, so I won't need to write the logs.

I've looked up by internet, and I've found the different ways to configure the logging interceptors but nothing about what I'm looking for.

My project uses Spring and the webservice has been setted up like this:

log4j.properties

```
log4j.logger.ws.service.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor=INFO,wsServiceLog
log4j.logger.ws.service.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor=INFO, wsServiceLog

log4j.appender.wsServiceLog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.wsServiceLog.File=d:/logs/ws_service_methodTwo.log
log4j.appender.wsServiceLog.Append=true
log4j.appender.wsServiceLog.DatePattern='.'_yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.wsServiceLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.wsServiceLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss } %l %x: %m%n
```

applicationContext-ws.xml

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="service" implementor="#serviceImpl"
    address="/wsService" 
    serviceName="wsService" wsdlLocation="wsdl/wsService.wsdl">

    <!-- Interceptors for logging -->
    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logInboundWs"/>
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>
    <jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logOutboundWs"/>
    </jaxws:outInterceptors>
    <jaxws:outFaultInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logOutboundWs"/>
    </jaxws:outFaultInterceptors>
    <jaxws:inFaultInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logInboundWs"/>
    </jaxws:inFaultInterceptors>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

With this config, all the requests and responses are logged in the file. And I don't figure out how it would be setted up...

I've tried also setting the interceptors in the class which implements the web service, but even so, I don't know how to target to a single method to redirect the log...

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "ws.service.WsService")
@InInterceptors(interceptors = "ws.service.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor")
@OutInterceptors(interceptors = "ws.service.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor")
public class WsServiceImpl implements WsService
{
    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(WsServiceImpl.class);


    public String methodOne(){
    ...
    }

    public String methodTwo(){
    ...
    }

    public String methodThree(){
    ...
    }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example config:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
<!-- ============================== -->
<!-- Append SQL messages to a file. -->
<!-- ============================== -->
<appender name="SQL" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="TRACE" />
    <param name="File" value="sql-statement.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5000KB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="100" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>



<!-- =============================== -->
<!-- Application specific categories -->
<!-- =============================== -->
<category name="your specific package" additivity="true">
    <priority value="TRACE" />
    <appender-ref ref="SQL" />
</category>

<!-- Setup the Root category -->
<root>
    <priority value="ERROR" />
</root>
```

You basically can specify the package name and create different appender to save it in different file.
If you have multiple methods in one file, you can separate them in two classes to achieve different log files saving.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I need to have the two methods in the same class. Maybe it is not possible to do what I need